# Changing schemas in mongoDB/mongoose

Tags: mongodb, schema, database, nosql

I am getting started with mongoDB and mongoose. I was wondering how people manage **evolving schemas**. For example if i started with a schema like this:

```
user_ID : 123,
user_firstName : 'bob',
user_lastName : 'smith'
```

And evolved it to something like this:

```
user_ID: 123,
user_name: [first:'bob', last:'smith']
```

**How could I update or manage old records that were established using the old schema design?**

Answer (score 18):

One approach to migrating document schemas involving simple data transformations would be to use [$exists](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-%24exists) to find documents that are missing the new fields and migrate them.

For example, transforming firstName and lastName into a new user_name field:

```
db.mycollection.find( { user_name : { $exists : false } } ).forEach(
    function (doc) {
        doc.user_name = {'first': doc.user_firstName, 'last': doc.user_lastName};

        // Remove old properties
        delete doc.user_firstName;
        delete doc.user_lastName;

        // Save the updated document
        db.mycollection.save(doc);
    }
)
```

For more complex migrations some tools that could be helpful are:

- [schema.js](http://skratchdot.com/projects/mongodb-schema/) or [variety](https://github.com/variety/variety) for analyzing the current schema of a collection
- [JSV: JSON Schema Validator](https://github.com/garycourt/JSV) for validating documents

Comment: deleting properties that way didn't work for me. I needed to use something like this `db.mycollection.update({}, { $unset: { user_firstname: 1, user_lastname: 1 } }, { multi: true })`